# How to get any currency format to be converted into "de-de" in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, currency

I get the currency values from a website... they could be in **any** currency format as the site is various in multiple countries.

what i currently have:

```
var actualPriceString = actualPriceElement.Text;
var actualPriceDe = Convert.ToDecimal(actualPriceString).ToString("C0", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-de"));
var maxPriceDe = Convert.ToDecimal(product.Max_Price).ToString("C0", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-de"));

if (Convert.ToDecimal(actualPriceDe) <= Convert.ToDecimal(maxPriceDe))
  run = await ClickElement(_config.site.add_to_cart, driver);
```

which just gives me errors or not what I wat at all.

I get errors when convert to decimal:

```
exception.Message = "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

The currency formats can look like those for example:
3.399,00 or
3,399.00

I also tried finding results online but all I get is from one currency Format to any other...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: They give you errors, why not share those errors with us? Also, if they can be in _any_ format, does that also mean that you can have combinations of decimal and thousands separators? For example: 14.192,55€ and £81,783.21?

Comment: yes thats what the formats look like. The only error i get is:
```
exception.Message = "Input string was not in a correct format."
```
because of the convert.todecimal

Comment: If there's *guarantee* that "any" formats are either `3.399,00` or `3,399.00` 
you can *detect* decimal separator - `char separator = actualPriceString[actualPriceString.Length - 3];`

Comment: okay but how will the seperator help me convert the value to a decimal or int i can Compare with a max value? 

Lets say the max_value is 2000.
from the website I get a price of 2.100,21 or 2,100.21 

i need to check if the value from the website is less than my max_price value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't solve the problem in *general case*, however, we can fight for some restricted cases:

1. We assume that negative value uses simple leading `-`: `-123.456,78`
2. We assume that we have no more than `2` positions for cents
3. We assume that decimal and group separators are not mixed: `12,45,67 == 123456`
4. We ignore currency symbols, all sums are assumed to be in euro

**Code:**

```
public static decimal MyConversion(string value) {
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    throw new FormatException("Not a valid currency");

  value = string.Concat(value
    .Reverse()
    .SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c))
    .Reverse()
    .SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c) && c != '-'));

  HashSet<char> separators = new HashSet<char>();
  int suggestSeparatorIndex = -1;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length);

  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i) {
    char c = value[i];

    if (char.IsDigit(c))
      sb.Append(c);
    else if (c == '-' && i == 0)
      sb.Append(c);
    else if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) 
      if (separators.Add(c))
        suggestSeparatorIndex = sb.Length;
      else
        suggestSeparatorIndex = -1;
  }

  if (suggestSeparatorIndex >= 0 && suggestSeparatorIndex >= sb.Length - 2)
    sb.Insert(suggestSeparatorIndex, '.');

  return decimal.Parse(sb.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + 0.00m;
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "3.399,00", 
    "3,399.00",
    "123,345,789.0",
    "123.1",
    "12.23.45", // here '.' is a group separator
    "123",
    "456 $ 89 cents", // we ignore $ here, no currency exchange will be done
    "$56.89",
    "123=35 (euro)",
    "56 Евро 89 центов", // Russian, stands for 56 Euro 89 cents
  };

  // Deutschland Kultur (German Culture settings)
  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-De");

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,25} => {MyConversion(test)}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
             3.399,00 => 3399,00
             3,399.00 => 3399,00
        123,345,789.0 => 123345789,00
                123.1 => 123,10
             12.23.45 => 122345,00
                  123 => 123,00
       456 $ 89 cents => 456,89
               $56.89 => 56,89
        123=35 (euro) => 123,35
    56 Евро 89 центов => 56,89
```